# SWI-Prolog reading a file for single digit numbers and adding them together

Tags: prolog

I am trying to read an input file and take only the single integers from the file and add them together and print the output to another file. The code I have works only if the file contains just single digit integers.

```
main :- 
    write('Name of input file ending with a period: '), 
    read(IN), 
    intsum(IN, 'numsum.txt').

intsum(IN, OUT) :- 
    see(IN),
    tell(OUT), 
    get(X), 
    process(X,0,R),
    write(R),
    seen,
    told.

process(-1, Y, Y).
process(X1,Y1,R1) :- 
    X1 < 48, 
    X1 > 57, 
    get(X3), 
    process(X3, Y1, R1). /* this line is what I am trying to use to check to see if the current value from the file is an integer */
process(X, Y, R) :- 
    X \= -1, 
    Y2 is Y + X - 48, 
    get(X2),  
    process(X2, Y2, R).`
```

The second process call is where I am trying to check to see if the current value read is and integer. I know that what is getting read from the input file is in ASCII when read. So I am checking to see if that value falls between the ASCII values for integers. If the value is not in ASCII value range for integers it will get the next input and check that one.

The third process call is checking for end of file and if not end of file and the read value is an integer then it will begin adding to the total.

The **input.txt** file contains: `1 2 b 3 4 c 5` and when the program is ran I get `116` as the output. I am looking for the result to be `15`. When the file contains only: `1 2 3 4 5` the result is `15`.

I am just struggling working out the kinks with making sure the value is an integer and if it is not one then just get the next value in the file.

Comment: `X1 < 48, X1 > 57` here, X1 cannot be below 48 AND above 57 at the same time, so this is never true. Maybe carefully use `;` or write two separate versions of process for those cases?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
intsum(In, Out) :-
    see(In),
    tell(Out),
    intsum(0),
    told,
    seen.

intsum(S) :-
    get_code(C),
    (   C = -1                   % C is end of file
    ->  write(S)
    ;   (   between(0'0, 0'9, C) % C is digit
        ->  S1 is S + C - 0'0
        ;   S1 = S ),            % C is not digit
        intsum(S1) ).
```

Note that the conditional construct `(`*Condition* `->` *Then* `;` *Else*) avoids spurious choice points. The ASCII codes of the characters `'0'` and `'9'` can be represented, respectively, as `0'0` and `0'9`. Predicate [get/1](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=get/1) is deprecated and it is better to use predicate [get_char/1](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=get_char/1). It is also recommended to use  [ISO compliant I/O](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=isoIO) instead of [Edinburgh-style I/O](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=edinburghIO).